# ImportError when ruamel.yaml is installed in a custom folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ruamel.yaml

I am facing a similar situation to the questions asked here: [Python Import error on installing ruamel.yaml in custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586651/python-import-error-on-installing-ruamel-yaml-in-custom-directory/49661763#49661763)

I am aware that we will want to use some form of python environment isolation mechanism like virtualenv to create isolated environments within which our python code can run. However, in the industry I'm in, it is not uncommon that we write several pieces of python packages that will need to be used within  other off-the-shelf software that come with their own python interpreter and so we are limited by the python version that the software(e.g. autodesk maya) uses and we don't have the flexibility of using virtualenv.

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=\\vm-fs-001\prod\sww\proj\general\python\python-2.7.14" <package_name>
```

We deploy these code that we write into a custom 3rd party directory using something similar to the above command. We set our environments to include the site-packages and scripts of the 3rd party deployment folder.

```
PYTHONPATH=\\vm-fs-001\prod\sww\proj\general\python\python-2.7.14\Lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

PATH=\\vm-fs-001\prod\sww\proj\general\python\python-2.7.14\Scripts;%PATH%;
```

In this case, the software is bundle with a python 2.7.14 interpreter and we wrote a package that requires ruamel.yaml

I get the below error when trying to import ruamel.yaml within the python interpreter of the 3rd party software.

```
ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml
```

I get the same ImportError even if I were to import ruamel from within my standard python 2.7.14 interpreter.

```
λ python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ruamel.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '\\\\vm-fs-001\\prod\\sww\\proj\\general\\python\\python-2.7.14\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', '\\\\vm-dc-001\\RedirectedFolders$\\nelson.lim\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
>>>
```

However, if I add an `__init__.py` here: `\\vm-fs-001\prod\sww\proj\general\python\python-2.7.14\Lib\site-packages\ruamel\__init__.py` and make the ruamel folder a package instead of a namespace folder, the import error will go away.

It seems as though there are issues with importing packages with namespaces that are installed in custom folders.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The issue is with `ruamel.yaml` itself, which has an awful installer.  The author wrote horrible, horrible hacks with .pth files to try and get namespace package working on Python 2.  You are not the first to have issues, and you won't be the last, because reasonable requests to write a sane installer have been closed as [wontfix](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues/28/consider-making-ruamelyaml-available-as-a).

Answer (score 0):

[Namespaces are a honking great idea](https://zen-of-python.info/namespaces-are-one-honking-great-idea--lets-do-more-of-those.html), but unfortunately the implementation for namespace packages has some issues, that the `ruamel.yaml` installer has to work around. Although I don't do anything to the `.pth` files in the installer for `ruamel.yaml` a `--prefix`-ed install doesn't seem to process those the same way as a non-prefixed install.

The `ruamel.yaml` installer is data driven, and the `setup.py` is common between many packages. Rewriting and testing all of those would take a lot of time without any functional improvement, and so far nobody is willing to pay for that (and it would probably better spent to improve the namespace package mechanism).

Apart from completely repacking `ruamel.yaml`, you should be able to create the  `ruamel/__init__.py` if it doesn't exists when your own package is loaded before you do `from ruamel.yaml import YAML` (assuming your package is depending on `ruamel.yaml`). If `ruamel.yaml` is an optional install, or as a general workaround, I suggest you create a package `ruamel_yaml` that creates that file (i.e. `PREFIX/ruamel/__init__.py`), in its `__init__.py` if that file doesn't exists and then does `from ruamel.yaml import *`.

Such an approach at least works on Linux based installs when you do prefix installs using:

```
pip install --prefix=/path/to/some/directory ruamel_yaml-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

A `setup.py` that creates such a package:

```
from setuptools import setup

import os
from textwrap import dedent

pkg = 'ruamel_yaml'
os.makedirs(pkg)
with open(pkg + '/__init__.py', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(dedent("""\
    import sys
    import os

    fn = __file__.replace('ruamel_yaml', 'ruamel').replace('__init__.pyc', '__init__.py')
    if not os.path.exists(fn):
        with open(fn, 'w'):
            pass

    from ruamel.yaml import *
    """))

with open('setup.cfg', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('[bdist_wheel]\nuniversal = 1\n')


setup(name=pkg,
      version='0.1',
      description='wrapper for --prefix installations of ruamel.yaml',
      author='Your Name',
      url='http://someurl.com',
      author_email='your@email',
      license='MIT',
      install_requires=['ruamel.yaml'],
      packages=[pkg],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Create the `ruamel_yaml-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl` with:

```
pip install wheel
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

If necessary, that generated `__init__.py` should also implement the steps to "make the ruamel folder a package instead of a namespace folder" (it is not clear to me what that entails), if that is required on Windows/for Maya.

Comment: Anthon, did you seriously just _delete_ the `ruamel.yaml` [issue 28](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues/28/consider-making-ruamelyaml-available-as-a)? Why? It had tons of helpful info from the conda guys and others for how to workaround the problems with this installer!  If possible, please restore it, so the discussion (and the reasons for your final decision) remains visible for users of your library.

Comment: First of all thanks @Anthon for the answers and for ruamel.yaml. To answer your questions. 

I used the --install-option flag instead of the --prefix flag because I did not know that pip now supports the --prefix flag.

Also, there wasn't anything special in the `__init__.py` it was an empty file. I thought that by adding an `__init__.py` under the ruamel folder, made it no longer a namespace but a package.

When you meant to create the ruamel/__init__.py before we do a `from ruamel.yaml import YAML`, did you mean to create it programmatically before the import statement or manually?

Comment: @nelson I would make the programmatically, as then you can't forget if you (or someone else) sets up a new machine with Maya. Don't worry to  much about it still being a namespace package or not. After that file is added you can do `from ruamel.yaml import YAML` that is what is important. It would be nicer if the package in the answer would do a one-time install, but that requires a self-modifying __init__.py (the one for `ruamel_yaml`) or a much more complicated `setup.py` for that package (the later would of course have my preference as you never have to do `import ruamel_yaml`)

Comment: @Nelson if you would like to test a version of `ruamel_yaml` that adds the `__init__.py` during **setup**, let me know (via email e.g.). I have no way of testing this myself with Maya